# How to construct a list of lengths efficiently

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering

Say I have a sorted list of integers

```
RandomInteger[{1, 100000}, 10000] // Sort // Short
```

I want to construct another list whose $m$-th element is the number of elements in the original list that are less than or equal to $m$:

```
Table[Length@Select[%, LessEqualThan[m]], {m, 10000}]
```

This is terribly inefficient, but for some reason I cannot come up with a better a approach. What's a better way to accomplish this? This seems to be a fairly standard exercise, so there should be plenty of duplicates, but I can find none. 
I am probably missing a key word...

Comment: What do you want to do with the table? What's your original problem? It sounds like you want to build some kind of CDF table manually. Maybe an `EmpiricalDistribution` or `BinCounts` already can accomplish what you want?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the usual [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep) + [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total) tricks:

```
r1 = Table[Total[UnitStep[m-s]], {m,10000}]; //AbsoluteTiming

r2 = Table[Length@Select[s,LessEqualThan[m]],{m,10000}];//AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.435358, Null}
>
> {41.4357, Null}
>
> True

**Update**

As @J42161217 points out, you can take advantage of the fact that the data is sorted to speed things up. He used [`Differences`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Differences). Here is a version that uses [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) instead:

```
mincounts[s_] := With[
    {
    unique = DeleteDuplicates@Nearest[s->"Element",s][[All,-1]],
    counts = Prepend[0] @ DeleteDuplicates@Nearest[s->"Index",s][[All,-1]]
    },
    With[{near = Nearest[unique->"Index", Range @ Length @ s][[All,1]]},
        counts[[1+near-UnitStep[unique[[near]]-Range@Length@s-1]]]
    ]
]
```

Comparison:

```
SeedRandom[1];
s=RandomInteger[{1,100000},10000]//Sort;

(* my first answer *)
r1 = Table[Total[UnitStep[m-s]], {m,10000}]; //AbsoluteTiming
(* J42161217's answer *)
r2 = Flatten[
    Join[
        {Table[0, s[[1]] - 1]}, 
        Table[Table[i, Differences[s][[i]]], {i, Length[Select[s, # <= 10000 &]]}]
    ]
][[;;10000]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* using Nearest *)
r3 = mincounts[s]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2 === r3
```

> {0.432897, Null}
>
> {0.122198, Null}
>
> {0.025923, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Ah, great answer, as usual.

Comment: Can you please check my answer because my laptop is very slow

Answer (score 15):

[`BinCounts`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinCounts.html) and [`Accumulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) combination is faster than all the methods posted so far:

```
r4 = Accumulate @ BinCounts[s, {1, 1 + 10000, 1}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00069

versus Henrik Schumacher's `mySparseArray`, Carl Woll's `mincounts` and J42161217's `Differences`-based method:

```
r5 = Accumulate[mySparseArray[Partition[s, 1] -> 1, {s[[-1]]}, Total, 0][[
      1 ;; Length[s]]]
      ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00081

```
r3 = mincounts[s]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.016

```
r2 = Flatten[Join[{Table[0, s[[1]] - 1]}, 
       Table[Table[i, Differences[s][[i]]], {i, 
             Length[Select[s, # <= 10000 &]]}]]][[;; 10000]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.149

```
r2 == r3 == r4 == r5
```

> True

Comment: Beat me to it - BinCounts is the way... +1

Comment: Hey @ciao, you are back?!!

Comment: Sorry @Henrik; thanks for the edit.

Comment: Short and fast. No need sorting.. Excellent!!... +1

Comment: @kglr - Been here all along, just busy herding a couple of startups, but I read several times a week, and usually learn something new each time.

Answer (score 12):

I think this is at least x3 faster than Mr. Carl Woll's answer
Can anybody compare my timing?

```
r3 = Flatten[Join[{Table[0, s[[1]] - 1]}, 
Table[Table[i, Differences[s][[i]]], {i, 
    Length[Select[s, # <= 10000 &]]}]]][[;;10000]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.157123, Null}

Using MapThread the same code is way faster

```
r6 = Flatten[
 Join[{Table[0, s[[1]] - 1]}, 
  MapThread[
   Table, {Range[t = Length[Select[s, # <= 10000 &]]], 
    Differences[s][[1 ;; t]]}]]][[;; 10000]]; // AbsoluteTiming   

r6===r3
```

> {0.008387, Null}
>
> True

Comment: These are the timing on my laptop r1={0.444354, Null},r2={39.456, Null},r3={0.157123, Null}
True

Comment: Hey, thanks for checking. I will use your timing. Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 6):

```
s = Sort[RandomInteger[{1, 100000}, 10000]];
```

Let us just imagine for the moment that the target list `r` is supposed to have length `100000` (we can truncate it afterwards). Then for each entry `i` in the list `s`, the list `r` needs to have a jump of height `1` at position `i`. The jumps are the "derivative" of `r` (in a discrete sense) and the antiderivative can be obtained with `Accumulate`. In order to get the list of jumps, we need additive matrix assembly.

This can be done with this function:

```
mySparseArray[rules_, dims_, f_: Total, background_: 0.] := 
 If[(Head[rules] === Rule) && (rules[[1]] === {}),
  rules[[2]],
  With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]},
   Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    SetSystemOptions[
     "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> f}],
    SparseArray[rules, dims, background],
    SetSystemOptions[spopt]]
   ]
  ]
```

So, in total, `r` can be obtained as follows:

```
r4 = Accumulate[
 mySparseArray[Partition[s, 1] -> 1, {s[[-1]]}, Total, 0][[1 ;; Length[s]]]
 ]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00055

For comparison:

```
r3 = Flatten[
      Join[{Table[0, s[[1]] - 1]}, 
       Table[Table[i, Differences[s][[i]]], {i, 
         Length[Select[s, # <= 10000 &]]}]]][[;; 10000]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
r3 == r4
```

> 0.116
>
> True